# how can I separate 2 divs equally from left and right?

Tags: html, css

Im a new in css and html. How can I separate 2 divs equally from left and right?? Here's my html code.

```
<div class="first-div">
    <h1>About<h1>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
    <h1>Services<h1>
</div>
```

Comment: A simple flexbox will do this trick, have a container and set it display:flex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equal vertical spacing with a Flexbox column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260534/equal-vertical-spacing-with-a-flexbox-column)

Comment: There are many methods to achieve it. Just google your question and you will get plenty of answers even with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. Learn [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/) grid or [flexbox](https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox) that would be easy for these kinds of task.

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;  /* for display it's child div beside each other */
}
.first-div,.second-div{
  width:50%;    /* for divide container into 2 equal divs  */
  border: 1px solid black; /*  for border around divs     */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="first-div">
    <h1>About<h1>
</div>

<div class="second-div">
    <h1>Services<h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several options and it all depends on your exact use case.

The first option is to set both to `50%` of the available width (left and right):

```css
.first-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <h1>About</h1>
</div><div class="second-div">
  <h1>Services</h1>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.first-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.second-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-div">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="second-div">
    <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're not familiar with flex, [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) is a great interactive way to learn.

---

And a final option is to use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-div">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="second-div">
    <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're not familiar with grid, [grid garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/) is a great interactive way to learn.

---

Sidenote: make sure to also properly close the `<h1>` tags with a `</h1>`.

Comment: flex froggy is nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Hope it useful for your question.

```css
 /* CSS */
 .container-box{
     width:100%;
     display:flex;
    }
    .first-div,.second-div{
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid #ddd;   //just to look
    }
```

```html
 <!-- HTML -->     
    
    <div class="container-box">
      <div class="first-div">
        <h1>About<h1>
      </div>
    
      <div class="second-div">
          <h1>Services<h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Css FlexBox .

[FlexBox Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```html
<div class="mainContainer" style="
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    ">
    
    <div class="first" style="
        border: 1px solid;
    ">
        <h1>About</h1><h1>
    </h1></div>
    
    <div class="second-div">
        <h1>Services</h1><h1>
    </h1></div>
 </div>
```